# Listing items in multi-select dropdown

Tags: office-ui-fabric

For a multi-select dropdown, is it possible to display one selected item (+ number of remaining items)

[image]

instead of listing all items in the textbox:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is supported to customize via [`Dropdown.onRenderTitle`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/dropdown):

> Optional custom renderer for selected option displayed in input

For example:

```
<Dropdown
    onRenderTitle={this.handleRenderTitle}
    ...    
/>
```

where

```
private handleRenderTitle(items: IDropdownOption[]) {
    if(items.length === 1) {
      return <>{`${items[0].text}`}</>;
    }
    return <>{`${items[0].text} (+ ${items.length - 1})`}</>;
}
```

**Result**

[image]